# how can I choose to send pass different props to a react component according to the current viewport size?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Is there a way to pass different props to a component according to the current viewport size?

I know you can get the current height and width using

```
var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
```

Image between 1440px and 1000px I have send some data to a component, and when it viewport shrinks below 1000px and above 768px I need to send another set of data to that component. How can I achieve this functionality in React?

Comment: Can you show us more code where you pass the data?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to handle this. I would recommend to make use of the ResizeObserver API:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver

There are polyfills for this if needed:
https://github.com/juggle/resize-observer

You can set the props you want to send in your component state, and then listen for a resize event. When the window resizes you get the new window size and set the props you want to pass to the component in the state accordingly. A rerender is triggered by React and the props, belonging to your window size, are passed to the child component.

Answer (score 0):

You could create listener for `resize` event and provide decide if it is mobile or not or anything else based upon the width (`isMobile` being an example).

**Code below using this approach**

But this approach would affect performance because of unnecessary renders. Then you would want to add `debouncing` or `throttling` for performance improvements.

**So to avoid this I would recomended using [react-sizes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sizes)**

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isMobile: false
  }

  handleWindowResize = () => {
    this.setState({ isMobile: window.innerWidth < 480 });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.onWindowResize);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onWindowResize);
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.props;
    const { isMobile } = this.state;

    return (
      <SomeComponent isMobile={isMobile}>
        {items}
      </SomeComponent>
    );
  }
}
```

[Reference of code](https://medium.com/@renatorib/tackling-responsive-elements-in-react-and-why-ive-created-react-sizes-f7c87e3f9e64)

Hope it helps!!!